# Chrome 90 removed #intensive-wake-up-throttling Flag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I noticed with the newest release of Chrome 90 that the flag for intensive-wake-up-throttling has been removed.

Just curious if anyone knows what happened to the flag/setting in this new version of Chrome? I've searched the release notes as well as the deprecated/removed and dev/beta forums for any mention.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: start at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4718288976216064, take it from there?

Comment: Thank you, I did, it holds no further information regarding the setting in Chrome 90. Directs me to GitHub to post an issue. Hopefully, that will provide answers.

Comment: I mean, that's what you want, right? SO is your last resort for when you've run out of authoritative places to check, asking on github instead of on SO seems exactly what you want in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To display the flag chrome://flags/#intensive-wake-up-throttling just enable the flag chrome://flags/#temporary-unexpire-flags-m89 then relaunch

Comment: Wouldn't this be a temporary fix though?  Presumably the second flag you provide will also go away in a version or two.

Comment: Indeed, this is a temporary solution, which is what I have found for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It was added back in Chrome 91
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/flags-dev/c/z6jZca-dfTM